# How to express this constraint: There is a singer in more than one band

Tags: alloy

I want to express this constraint: *There is a singer in more than one band.*

The following declares Band and Singer. The relation "band" maps Singer to Band.

```
sig Band {}

sig Singer {
  band: Band
}
```

This appears to express the desired constraint:

```
some s: Singer | some s.band
```

Upon reflection, I don't think that is correct. It says (I believe) that there is a singer in ***one or more*** bands. (Am I correct?)

I want the constraint to say that there is a singer in ***more than one*** band.

I figured this should express the desired constraint:

```
some s: Singer | #s.band > 1
```

But the Alloy tool says that no instances can be generated. Why? Why is it incorrect? What is the correct way to express the desired constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alloy Analyzer says that no instances can be generated because of the way your field band is declared.

By default, not having a multiplicity keyword in a field declaration means that the multiplicity is **exactly one**. 
In the Alloy model you gave, the band field thus relate a given singer to exactly one band, hence ruling out any instance where a singer sings in more than one band.

Adding the multiplicity keyword **some** to your field declaration should thus do the trick.

```
sig Band {}

sig Singer {
  band: some Band
}
```

The constraint you proposed last `some s: Singer | #s.band > 1` is indeed enforcing that at least one signer should sing in strictly more than one band.

Comment: my pleasure ;-)